# Availability of OnSend for MAC?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

OnSend for OWA is already available for over a year and since then the microsoft documentation says 'will be available for other platforms soon'. Beginning of this year MS said that it would be available by the end of this quarter. Since then there has been no updates. Can somebody please give an update about the status; is it in development, when will it be released, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

onSend for Mac and Windows is available on Insiders fast builds. You have to opt in to the Office Insiders program-> Insider fast to access these builds.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way I could have known that? To track these insider program options?

Comment: https://insider.office.com/en-us/join. This link has details on how to join office insiders program. please opt for the Insiders fast channel here to use on send